# how to retrieve the last updated data from multiple categories using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to retrieve the last updated data from multiple categories using php and mysql.

For example:

**Category Table:**

```
id categoryName
1   test1
2   test2
3   test3
```

**Product Table**

```
id categoryId productName dateTime
1   1         product1    2010-05-06 10:00:37
2   1         product2    2010-05-06 10:10:41
3   2         product3    2010-05-06 10:20:53
4   2         product4    2010-05-06 10:22:44
```

**Now, My o/p Should be**

```
id categoryId productName dateTime
2   1         product2    2010-05-06 10:10:41
4   2         product4    2010-05-06 10:22:44
```

How can this be done using mysql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, c.id, p.productName, p.dateTime
FROM Category c, Product p
WHERE c.id = p.categoryId
AND p.id = (SELECT id FROM Product WHERE categoryId = c.id ORDER BY dateTime DESC LIMIT 1)
```